# Issue update Select Case With Function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

i have an issue to do update data with function in PostgreSQL database. i do update on tbltemp table and it got good result in 1st rows but in 2nd rows it doesn't update, the sql code and table something like this:

tblbuy_transactionhdr table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
header_id|transaction_type|account_no|accounts_code|amount|type
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
BTR100001|Credit          |1700001 |           201 |60000 | 103
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

tbltemp table:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    temp_id|accounts_code|accounts_name|description|debit|credit
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1      |103        |Inventory     |BTR1000001 |   600 |  0
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2      |101        |Cash          |BTR1000001 |     0 |600 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this's function for update tbltemp table:

```
IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN 
//this for update 1st row and the result is ok 
update tbltemp set debit=new.sub_amount, credit=0, 
temp_status=temp_status where description=new.header_id and accounts_code 
= '103' and temp_id=temp_id;

//this for update 2nd rows but this is the problem       
update tbltemp set 
accounts_code = (SELECT CASE WHEN transaction_type='Cash' THEN  '101'
         ELSE '201'
         END AS accounts_code from tblbuy_transactionhdr where 
         transaction_type=transaction_type order by header_id desc LIMIT 1),

accounts_name= (SELECT CASE WHEN transaction_type='Cash' THEN 'Cash'
        ELSE 'Account Payable'       
        END AS accounts_name from tblbuy_transactionhdr  where 
        transaction_type=transaction_type order by header_id desc LIMIT 1),

        debit=0, credit=new.sub_amount, temp_status=temp_status where accounts_code=(SELECT CASE WHEN transaction_type='Cash' THEN '101'
        ELSE '201'
        END AS accounts_code from tblbuy_transactionhdr where 
        transaction_type=transaction_type order by header_id desc LIMIT 1) 
        and description=new.header_id and temp_id=temp_id;  
        return new;
        END IF;
        end;
```

i would like to update in 2nd rows when i do update data on tblbuy_transaction with transaction_type='Credit' then the resuslt is  accounts_code='201' and accounts_name='Accounts Payable' but it doesn't work, what's wrong on  function script? thanks.

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? Do you get an error? Or you get updated values different from what you want (if so, what exactly values do you get)?

Comment: thanks before Marat for your response, sorry for my late.  : Or you get updated values different from what you want? yes, it doesn't work in 2nd rows . i don't know what  wrong in my SQL script .